# Exporting svg with transform value result in gray line at beginning in D3js - Canvg

Tags: css, d3.js, svg, canvg

I ma exporting my svg created in D3js using cannvg. Whenever there is transform value to svg, a gray line is coming in exported image. If we remove gray line is gone. (Line is displayed in green circle)

[image]

Here is my code for svg

```
              var svg = mapContainer.append("svg")
                  .attr("width", width)
                  .attr("fill","#fff")
                  .attr("transform","translate(100, 0)")
                  .attr("height", height);
```

I am using canvg to export this svg.

```
  var canvasBase = document.createElement('canvas');
    var html = d3.select("svg")
                  .node().parentNode.innerHTML;
    canvg(canvasBase, html)
```